# How to update the bottom row(first empty row) of sheet with data using pygsheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I have a spreadsheet linked with the python module with 3 columns. I have tried to insert the new row of data using `insert_rows` function but it does not do anything and also does not throw any error, making it harder for me to narrow down the problem.

Here is what I have tried:

```
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='File.json')

sh = gc.open('TwitterStream')

wks = sh[0]

t = Twython('ckey ','c_secret ')

results = t.search(q='tuberculosis', count=5, lang='en', result_type='popular',tweet_mode='extended')
all_tweets = results['statuses']

for tweet in all_tweets:
        tweetString = tweet["full_text"]
        userMentionList = tweet["entities"]["user_mentions"]
        if len(userMentionList)>0:
            for eachUserMention in userMentionList:
                name = eachUserMention["screen_name"]
                time = tweet["created_at"]
//This is the function
                wks.insert_rows(wks.rows, number=1,values=[tweetString, name, time], inherit=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to append the values to the next row of the last row onthe Spreadsheet using pygsheets with python.
- You have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

For this, how about this answer? In this answer, I would like to propose to use the method of `append_table`. For this, at first, the values for putting to the sheet are created, and then, the created values are put to the sheet using the method of `append_table`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
for tweet in all_tweets:
        tweetString = tweet["full_text"]
        userMentionList = tweet["entities"]["user_mentions"]
        if len(userMentionList)>0:
            for eachUserMention in userMentionList:
                name = eachUserMention["screen_name"]
                time = tweet["created_at"]
                wks.insert_rows(wks.rows, number=1,values=[tweetString, name, time], inherit=True)
```

To:

```
values = []  # Added
for tweet in all_tweets:
    tweetString = tweet["full_text"]
    userMentionList = tweet["entities"]["user_mentions"]
    if len(userMentionList) > 0:
        for eachUserMention in userMentionList:
            name = eachUserMention["screen_name"]
            time = tweet["created_at"]
            values.append([tweetString, name, time])  # Added

wks.append_table(values, start='A1', end=None, dimension='ROWS', overwrite=True)  # Added
```

- In this modification, `values` is appended to the next row of the last row of the sheet `wks`.
- In the specification of pygsheets, it seems that when `overwrite=True` is modified to `overwrite=False`, the new rows are added and put to the values.

#### Reference:

- [append_table](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html?highlight=append%20row#pygsheets.Worksheet.append_table)